# Selecting the most recent and the 6th most recent months from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe with 24 months of dates. How do I create a new dataframe that only include the most recent month in the dataframe and the 6th/nth most recent month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for equality of year and month for current date or current date minus 6 months.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range(dt.date(2019,9,1), dt.date(2021,9,1), freq="M")})

t = pd.to_datetime("today")
td = t - pd.Timedelta(days=365//2)

mask = (df.Date.dt.year.eq(t.year) & df.Date.dt.month.eq(t.month)) | (df.Date.dt.year.eq(td.year) & df.Date.dt.month.eq(td.month))
df2 = df[mask]

print(df2)
```

#### output

```
         Date
11 2020-08-31
17 2021-02-28
```